# c++ splitting a string and getting the part coming after whitespace

Tags: c++, string, split

I need to do a string splitting such that If I have a string like below

```
string foo="thisIsThe         Test     Input";
```

I need to get the part coming  after the multiple or single withspace. In this case I need to get `"Test    Input".` I know that I can get the first part by :

```
int index=foo.find(' ');
string subString=foo.substr(0,index);
```

But I dont know how could I do what I want. Is there anyone to help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::find_first_not_of` accepts a position argument which indicates where to start searching.  So use that to find the first non-space, starting at the first space.

```
int index=foo.find(' ');
index=foo.find_first_not_of(' ', index);
string subString=foo.substr(index);
```

Comment: He wants only the part containing "Test input". You should be getting from index to the end

Comment: @Ben-Voigt If a string does not include anything after whitespaces, it gives me error right ?

Comment: @Ben-Voigt or just empty string ?

Comment: @caesar: I'm not sure whether you get `out_of_range` thrown or an empty string.  If you're worried about that, test `index` against `string::npos`.

Comment: I think you get `out_of_range`.  Because `find_first_not_of` returns `string::npos` if the text is not found. `npos` is the maximum size for a string

Answer (score 0):

You can also copy to a new string char by char eliminating any spaces too. 
It will make it easier to use foo.find(' ');

**Eliminate all whitespace**

```
string foo = "thisIsThe         Test     Input";
string bar[100];

for (int i = 0; i < foo.length(); i++)
{
    if (foo[i] != ' ')
        bar[i] = foo[i];


}
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(bar) / sizeof(bar[i]); i++)
    cout << bar[i];
```

**Keep one space between each term:**

```
string foo = "thisIsThe         Test     Input";
    string bar[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < foo.length(); i++)
    {
        if (foo[i] != ' ')
            bar[i] = foo[i];

        else if (foo[i + 1] != ' ' && foo[i] == ' ')
            bar[i] = ' ';

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(bar)/sizeof(bar[i]); i++)


cout << bar[i];
```